# Custom sass build of Bootstrap 5 minus anything theme or component related

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

Basically, I just want to create a bootstrap build that uses only the utility classes and the grid.  So I don't need any components and I don't need anything color or theme related.  Essentially I don't need anything that isn't related to layout and spacing.  Does anyone have documentation for such a build, or a setup that's worked for them that they can share?

I've messed with it a little, but I've not had success at getting the scss import order correct or finding the exact right files to include or I'm doing something else wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@import "bootstrap-grid";` is all you need.

This will give you the grid (container,row,col) class and spacing/flex utilities. Also remember they provide a pre-built [grid only CSS version](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/contents/#css-files) as well.

[SASS demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/bcSc6hfETM)

Comment: Wow.  Too simple for complicated minds.  Exactly what I needed.  Thanks